# Why can't I dir %appdata% but can cd to it?

Tags: cmd, directory, environment-variables, virtual-machine

On my virtual machine, `dir %appdata%` yields the error `The system cannot find the path specified.` But `cd %appdata%` works. And after cd to it, I can dir it then. If I cd out, then I cannot dir it back. This still happens even when I run the shell as admin. The same with %localappdata%. However I can dir some other environment variables like %windir%

This doesn't happen in my host machine. Why is that?

Comment: Your issue is that your command(s) are using lazy syntax. You should always, for robustness, doublequote any file or directory paths, _(unless you are certain they will not contain spaces, or worse, poison characters)_. Examples: `CD /D "%AppData%"`, `Dir "%AppData%" /A:-D-L-S /B /O:N /S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because my account name has spaces, so any env that use the account name will have spaces, making cmd read it improperly.

Simply put those variables in double quotes to solve this.